# How to pass python args and docker env properly?

Tags: python, docker

I have python file which takes args which file path, file1, file2. For example,
`python my_py.py /files file1.txt file2.txt`
Inside of `my_py.py`,

```py
import os
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f1_read = f1.read()
print(f1_read)

f2 = open('file2.txt, 'r')
f2_read = f2.read()
print(f2_read)

db = os.environ('DB')
user_id = os.environ('UID')
password = os.environ('PWD')
print('db: {}, user: {}, password: {}'.format(db, user_id, password))
```

Inside of my Dockerfile

```
FROM centos7

RUN yum install -y update
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

After I build it and try to run it,

```
docker run -d -t my_image -e DB=my_db -e UID=myUser -e PWD=myPwd
```

Even though I use `-d`, it just exits right after I run it. what I am trying to do is, running this container and run python(`python my_py.py /files file1.txt file2.txt`) by using `exec`.

If I have different cmd in dockerfile,

```
CMD ['python' 'my_py.py', 'file1.txt' 'file2.txt']
```

and then run same `docker run` as above.
I get this error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-e\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Researching about it, it seems like it is wrong docker syntax but it is at least working earlier.

Is there anyway that I can have python args with docker env at same time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple small things wrong with what you've got

the first is the syntax of `CMD` -- it should either be `json` (recommended) or a shell line -- here's a correction for that:

(note you had two bugs here, one some commas were missing and two they need to be double quotes)

```
CMD ["python", "my_py.py", "file1.txt", "file2.txt"]
```

now the next part is that the position of flags in the docker command is sensitive (so it knows which flags go to `docker` and which flags go to your executable).  This is based on the first non-flag argument (the image) -- everything after that is flags to your executable and everything before that is flags to docker

adjusting your command:

```sh
docker run -d -t -e DB=my_db -e UID=myUser -e PWD=myPwd my_image
```

note also that you probably don't want to put passwords in the commandline since any user can read those via `ps` (security issue) -- you're probably better to use `--env-file`

Comment: I fixed my `CMD` as you pointed out. Once I run the docker command `docker run ...` as you said, it keeps exiting. I thought `-d` flag is for detached mode that it keeps running, isn't it?

Comment: The `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile is also causing problems: it causes `/bin/bash` to be inserted in front of any `CMD`, which you don't want (`python` is a native executable and not a shell script).  You can just delete that.

Comment: @DavidMaze I deleted. I only have `CMD` and my most concern is, it exits right after I run the docker

Comment: are you sure it's exiting? `-d` is "run in detached mode" which your commandline will exit immediately but the container will be running in the background

Comment: @AnthonySottile its status displays, `Exited (1)  x seconds ago`

Comment: what happens if you run it in the foreground, the error should be much more obvious and you can fix it from there